# Plotly: How to plot multiple columns on one scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
      col_1  col_2  col_3
0              True           True           True
1              True           True           True
2              True           True           True
3              True           True           True
4              True           True           True
```

I would like to create a plot where:

1. x axis is the index value
2. y axis has got three rows (one for each column), where a scatter point is present on that row if it is False. Else it is not present.

Is this possible?

Comment: Columns in a scatter plot? Could you include an image of what you would like to accomplish? The code for any attempts you've made would be great too. And perhaps a more complete dataset where alle the values are not equal to True, since the cases where the values are False seem to be of more interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this what you are after? I've set some random elements to False just to illustrate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[True]*3]*5, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df.iloc[0, 2] = False
df.iloc[1, 1] = False
df.iloc[4, 0] = False

x, y = np.where(df == False)
y = y + 1  # just to match example columns names

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'd like to do this with plotly, if possible. And, ideally, the y axis would be labeled with the names of the columns rather than arbitrary y values.

Comment: Oops, sorry, had totally missed the first word in your post!